# Website scraping to get breadcrumb categories

Tags: c#, html, regex, web-scraping

I am working on website scraping using c# win form application, I am trying to get each title in breadcrumb html. With my html code as

```
<div>
<span class="title">Home</span>
<span class="sep">/</span>
<span class="title">Cat1</span>
<span class="sep">Home</span>
<span class="title">Cat2</span>
<span class="sep">/</span>
<span class="title">Cat3</span>
</div>
```

Above html is in string format. I want to retrieve categories i.e Cat1 to Cat3 to write categories in excel files. How can I use Regex to get those 3 categories from string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex to match your string.

```
title">(.+)<
```

**Keep in mind, however, that:**

It will match *Home* as your first capturing group.

In your C# code, use the property `.Groups(1)` of your match object to return the first capturing group. `Groups(0)` would return the entire match.

Make sure to skip the first match to get *Cat1*, *Cat2* and *Cat3*.

No needless to say, your regex object must handles multiline.

### Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/pE7kY7/1).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
title">(.*?)<
```

Comment: No, giving match.success false.

Comment: what does the  `?` add here?

Comment: The ? isn't necessary for the HTML layout in the question, I included it to handle the possibility that the HTML may be evaluated as a single line as in https://regex101.com/r/dC5hW5/1